# Jenkins trigger for multiple scheduling

Tags: jenkins, scheduling

I know Jenkins must have multiple scheduling. But I can't find how to declare trigger with fiew conditions this like `0 10-18 * * 1-5` and `0 18-23 * * 6-7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can provide multiple schedules to a single job as required