# how to task a job to trigger with 2 different cron in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job which I would like to be ran everyday at midnight and then Fridays at 18, I have tried this: `triggers { cron('H 0 * * *  \n H 18 * * 5') }` but it does not seem to work so far so I end up creating another extra job for the friday run. Is there any way to actually do this in one job?

Comment: is this what you  mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562505/4311135 ?

Comment: I tried that but did not seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
triggers { cron("""H 0 * * *
H 18 * * 5""") }
```